# Flutter textfield onChanged - detect if last text typed in is a taghandle '@mention'

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm looking to create a textfield which upon `onChanged` detects if a user has typed the `@` tagHandle and trailing text (similar to a mention taghandle in twitter) which in turn will trigger the `_callToAction()`.

As a code example, the following code only triggers each time the `@` symbol is typed in:

```
TextField(
  onChanged: (value) {
    if (value.endsWith("@")) {
      _callToAction();
    }
  }
)
```

However this is not the desired result as i need to detect the trailing text after the `@` symbol (`@mention`) which should work both when the user is typing into the form and when they are backspacing and come across a previously typed `@mention` taghandle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution , it's not the optimized one but it does work.

Keep variable to check if `@` is detected and the other 2 variables to hold the index of the `@handle`.

```
bool detected = false;
int startIndexOfTag = 0;
int endIndexOfTag = 0;
```

And then in `onChanged` of the `TextField`

```
onChanged: (value) {
    if (value.endsWith('@')) {
      detected = true;
      startIndexOfTag = value.length - 1;
    }

    if (detected == true) {
      print(value.substring(startIndexOfTag));
    }

    if ((detected == true && value.endsWith(' ')) || startIndexOfTag == 1) {
      detected = false;
      endIndexOfTag = value.length;
    }

    if (value.length < endIndexOfTag) {
      detected = true;
      endIndexOfTag = value.length;
      startIndexOfTag = value.indexOf('@');
    }
  },
```

Here is a the [DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/5ac248df3575bc5a255bf6661a5fd956) for the same.

Comment: That's actually not an issue, the logic remains the same and it works fine. I guess I am getting script error because of the Stateless widget. If I replace it with Stateful I don't get the error. To be more specific on what's the error, I'll have to check it in an actual project.

Comment: yes logic is right, he will have to check each incoming word and maintain indexes.